# How to COUNT or similar without using HAVING on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, select

I have the following database:

**Movie**(*id_movie*, title, id_director(FK), year, duration, country, facebook_likes, imdb_score, gross, budget)
**Actor_Movie**(id_actor(FK), id_movie(FK))
**Person**(*id_person*, name, facebook_likes)
**Actor** (id_actor(FK))
**Director**(id_director(FK))
**Genre**
(*id_genre*, description)
  **Genre_Movie**(id_genre(FK), id_movie(FK))

I need to SELECT to find all the different Movies that the title begins with a number, and that have more than 4 different genres.

I have this Select, that does perfectly the find I want to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M1.title FROM Movie AS M1 NATURAL JOIN Genre_Movie AS GM NATURAL JOIN Genre AS G
WHERE (M1.title LIKE '0%' OR M1.title LIKE '1%' OR M1.title LIKE '2%' OR M1.title LIKE '3%' OR M1.title LIKE '4%'
OR M1.title LIKE '5%' OR M1.title LIKE '6%' OR M1.title LIKE '7%' OR M1.title LIKE '8%' OR M1.title LIKE '9%')
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(GM.id_genre) FROM Genre_Movie AS GM NATURAL JOIN Movie AS M2 
                WHERE M1.id_movie = M2.id_movie) > 4
ORDER BY M1.title;
```

But, now, I need to do it with the following rules:

1) Using a subquery at FROM.
2) Not using GROUP BY anywhere in the main query.
3) Not using HAVING anywhere.

I've been trying to do something like an A INNER JOIN B, using A table like the table that contains all the films with title beggining in a number, and B table like a table that contains all the films with more than 4 genres. The problem is that I don't know how to create the B table without using HAVING.

If you can help me doing the query following the rules.

Thanks you in advantage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.title
FROM Movie A
WHERE (A.title REGEXP '^\d*')=1 AND 
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_genre) 
       FROM Genre_Movie B 
       WHERE A.id_movie=B.id_movie)>4;
```

See [Regular Expressions on MySQL reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) on how to use regular expressions in mysql.